# JQuery Image Slider image not showing

Tags: jquery, image

I'm trying to create an image slider using JQuery (I've been advised that's the "correct" way to achieve this." I have the below code with the image under the projects root folder but it doesn't show? Not sure why?

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    <script src="../App_Themes/Project/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var imgs = [
    'myImage.png'];
        var cnt = imgs.length;

        $(function () {
            setInterval(Slider, 3000);
        });

        function Slider() {
            $('#imageSlide').fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(this).attr('src', imgs[(imgs.length++) % cnt]).fadeIn("slow");
            });
        }
    </script>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <img id="imageSlide" alt="" src="" />
    </div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In addition I would like arrows to allow navigation of each image - would I still be on the correct path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript is executing before the page has loaded, so the element that it's attached to doesn't yet exist. [$(document).ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) is a good function to use to delay the execution of the javascript until after the page has finished loading.

EDIT: as to the arrows, I think that would be best asked in a separate question with more details provided.

EDIT2: JsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/nTCJp/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Handler for .ready() called. 
    var imgs = ['http://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/images/logo_jquery_215x53.gif'];
    var cnt = imgs.length;
    setInterval(Slider, 3000);

    function Slider() {
        $('#imageSlide').fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $(this).attr('src', imgs[(imgs.length++) % cnt]).fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: My code now is:

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // Handler for .ready() called.
            
            var imgs = [
        'djq.png'];
            var cnt = imgs.length;

            $(function () {
                setInterval(Slider, 3000);
            });

            function Slider() {
                $('#imageSlide').fadeOut("slow", function () {
                    $(this).attr('src', imgs[(imgs.length++) % cnt]).fadeIn("slow");
                });
            }
        });
        </script>

but still not working?

Comment: @Jupiter I added your code to my answer, but changed a few things, the main one being the random function() that was left inside the .ready(function()). Your code actually works without errors, so I'm thinking your image source or your var imgs may be messed up. Check out the jsFiddle example.